# Force update Child Component when Parent Component changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

I'm using a library.
The library have some `Props`.
But, look like the library has prevented update when `Props` changed.
Like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    return JSON.stringify(nextState) !== JSON.stringify(this.state)
}
```

So, the Library just render once when `componentDidMount`.
How can i force update or force re-render or something when `Props` changed?
Thank you so much

Comment: could you please tell us what is that library if it's an open source project?

Comment: Of course: https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables,
When `props` name "columns" change. It's not re-render!

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with an uncontrolled component which means you can not change its value but you can re-mount it by changing its `key`. However, it can make some changes in the re-mounted component's `state`, but occasionally it would be possible to keep the child's state in the parent's `state` and pass those data to the re-mounted component as an `initialValue` or whatever it has.

Answer (score 0):

That code means your component will be re-rendered only when the state has been changed.

So if you want to re-render when your props are changed, just remove shouldComponentUpdate. Because, it's basic to be re-rendered when the props are changed.

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate is inside library.

Comment: One way is forking library and change module version to that repository